# How can I get this .sh file to run properly?

Tags: server, convert, .sh

I'm trying to take a .bat file and make it a .sh

This is the working .bat file

```bash
@echo off
title runserver
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe" -Xmx815m -cp bin;lib/*; com.rs.Launcher true true false
pause
```

this is my .sh file so far:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
java -Xmx815m -cp bin;lib/*; com.rs.Launcher true true false
pause
```

Is this wrong? Am I far off? I don't really know what I'm doing when it comes to .sh files so any help will be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is are you trying to do with the `java..` command? For a `.jar` file, you can use `java -jar FILE.jar`. You should be able to use `exit` in place of `pause`, which will exit the script after the java thing closes.

Comment: Im trying to get it to execute the Launcher file. (it does not open any windows other than the cmd window normally, it just stays open until I close it. (When you close it the server shutsdown)

Comment: Errr... I don't still don't know what you could do about the `java...` bit, but I have found a replacement for `title runserver` may be `PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -ne \"\033]0;$1 runserver\007\""`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the bat command uses the Windows Path Separator (`;`) to specify the classpath. In UNIX systems this is (`:`), thus we can change the script to:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -Xmx815m -cp bin:lib/*: com.rs.Launcher true true false
```

Comment: The closest equivalent for `pause` would be `read`, both commands waits for you to press Enter (with some unrelated differences). However, when using a GNU/Linux distribution, it is not unusual to run this command in a terminal where you do not want to pause before you return to the prompt, so I would suggest to remove `read` (or `exit`) completely.

Comment: Marcos Roriz Junior, thank you, it ran without errors. My only problem now is...did it work? Im running ubuntu server 12.04.3 and i dont know if it just ran then close or stayed open as a process? Im very new to ubuntu and my hope is to get this running as a process if that is possible

Answer (score 1):

To get it to stay open, in addition to [Marcos Roriz Junior](https://askubuntu.com/users/5950/marcos-roriz-junior)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/397829/176889), you can do:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
java -Xmx815m -cp bin:lib/*: com.rs.Launcher true true false
read -p 'Press Enter to continue...'
```

However, it may not open in a terminal window. If you double click the file and select *Run in Terminal* that will open a terminal, but if you are running it from the command line or with *Run* it will not.

Use this to always open in a terminal:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
[[ ! -t 0 ]] && exec gnome-terminal -e "$0 \"$@\""
java -Xmx815m -cp bin:lib/*: com.rs.Launcher true true false
read -p 'Press Enter to continue...'
```

NOTE: You may have to `cd` to the folder where the files are before the `java ...` command.